# is it possible to include two DLL libraries with same name in VB .net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2012, dll

I'm making a project with dotras library and I want to make the executable compatible with both windows 7 and windows XP. The point is that dotras has two different libraries with the same name (one for win 7 and one for win XP). I was wondering if it's possible to include both and, basing on the running O.S., load & use the right one.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 but I'm really new to it.
any suggestions/examples?

Answer (score 1):

Are the functions in the dotras library the same in both versions? Also are the assembly versions the same? If yes, you try using LoadLibrary. See [Loading dll library from Resource to Current Domain(Embedding dll in main exe file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443890/loading-dll-library-from-resource-to-current-domainembedding-dll-in-main-exe-fi)