# Pack a precompiled .NET 6 dll to an executable

Tags: c#, .net-core, dll

I'm writing a program in C#. I'd like to compile the program to a DLL file, which can be easily be done with the `dotnet` cli tool. However, I would then like to pack this dll, along with all of it's dependencies, into a single executable file for the specified platform, along with some configuration values which could be accessed in the C# code. I do not want to use Publish single file because the configuration values will vary and I don't want to need the source code every time I need a new executable. Is this possible? I can't find anything of the sort in Microsoft documentation or on Google.

Comment: Add them as binary resources, then hook in to `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` and load them from the resource binary

Comment: @Charlieface Do you have an example of how to do that? I'm not exactly sure what you mean by resource binary. I want to emulate the function of `dotnet publish` in single-file mode except separately from the DLL compilation

Comment: Are these third-party DLLs, or are they  other projects in the solution?

Comment: @Charlieface There's one main program dll written by me and then some nuget dependency dlls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading dll library from Resource to Current Domain(Embedding dll in main exe file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443890/loading-dll-library-from-resource-to-current-domainembedding-dll-in-main-exe-fi)

Comment: @Charlieface No. That seems to be some legacy .NET framework problem. The functionality seems to already exist in .NET core as seen when you publish in single-file mode, except I want to do it at a later date to the existing dll without republishing

Comment: You can do this when you compile the EXE rather than at the point you compile the DLL

Comment: @Charlieface Do you know of an example?

Comment: I just linked you one, not sure what is difficult to understand. It works the same way on .NET Core as on Framework: you add the DLLs as resources in your EXE project, then attach a `AssemblyResolve` handler to read the DLL from the resource and load it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `Fody.Costura` to automate the process of adding dependencies into your .exe as Resources, and adding the `AssemblyResolve` stub.

Simply run

```
PM> Install-Package Fody
PM> Install-Package Costura.Fody
```

On your executable project.

Answer (score -1):

So what you actually want is to publish as a single exe, but [exclude](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli#exclude-files-from-being-embedded) appsettings.json from the bundle?

```cs
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: where did that come from? I want to publish as just DLLs, and then link those into EXEs at a later time

Comment: If you want a single executable, then you do want to use the documented process to publish a single exe. Keeping the config out of the exe is not hard and shouldn't be a reason to attempt any other weird packaging method.

Comment: I don't want the config out of the exe. I have other reasons for wanting to do it afterward