# Can a call to Assembly.Load(byte[]) raise the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, clr, .net-assembly

Suppose I have a handler for [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event, and in the handler I construct a byte array and invoke the method [`Assembly.Load(byte[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx). Can this method itself cause the `AssemblyResolve` event to be raised again, and cause my handler to be re-entered?

My question is not restricted only to assemblies that can be generated using C# compiler, they can contain abritrary metadata and executable code supported by the CLR.

I did some experiments and haven't find any cases when it happens. I tried to load assemblies that require additional references, tried to add CAS attributes to the loaded assembly whose decoding would require another assembly, tried to load an assembly with a module initializer (global `.cctor` method). In no case I observed the `AssemblyResolve` event to be raised from inside the `Assembly.Load(byte[])` method, it only happened if some code later tried to access types, methods or attributes in the loaded assembly. But I can be missing something here.

Comment: what happens if you add some `assembly:` attribute to your assembly with static dependencies on a third assembly?

Comment: Yes, it is [technically possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/505333/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant As I mentioned in the question, I tried to use a module initializer, but it behaves as the static constructor for the special `<Module>` type that contains all global members declared in a module. The module initializer is being invoked only when some global member is actually accessed for the first time.

Comment: @chillitom I tried that, but it didn't work. Normally, attributes are just passive data unless they're explicitly read. Maybe there are some special attributes (that I don't know of) that are automatically read by CLR on an assembly load, and then I possibly could provide an enum argument to such an attribute, where the corresponding enum type is declared in an yet unresolved referenced assembly...

Comment: I use this quite a lot in IronScheme, but I cant say I have ever seen it happen (or I might have worked around it in the last 7 years ;p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge `Assembly.Load` or loading assembly by other means does not execute any constructors that can be generated by the C# compiler (including static constructors). As result you're not going to get reentrancy to `AssemblyResolve` on commonly found assemblies.

As you've mentioned in the question, module initializers are not executed during the `Load` call. Covered in list of guarantees in CLI spec - excerpt can be found in [Module Initializers](http://web.archive.org/web/20160214141518/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/19/494914.aspx) by Junfeng Zhang.

> B. The module’s initializer method is executed at, or sometime before, first access to any types, methods, or data defined in the module

There are related SO questions usually discussing "run code before any type constructors" like [Initialize library on Assembly load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459560/initialize-library-on-assembly-load). Note that [.Net: Running code when assembly is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505237/net-running-code-when-assembly-is-loaded/505333#505333) has an answer by Marc Gravell that states it may not be possible due to security constraints.

Comment: Thanks. I did not intend to restrict my question only to assemblies that can generated using C# compiler. I updated the question to make it clear.

Comment: Answers to the question you referenced apparently do not provide any way make a code to be executed immediately during a call to `Assembly.Load(byte[])`. Attributes are passive data unless they're explicitly read, and a module initializer (I mentioned it in the question) is only invoked before an attempt to access a globally declared member. Maybe there are some special attributes that are automatically read by CLR on an assembly load, and then I could provide an enum argument to such an attribute, where the enum type is declared in a referenced assembly...

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov - ? "just add a static constructor to the <Module> class" (based on http://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/) looks like closest thing to what you are looking for to me. I have no personal experience when it will be called.

Comment: I tried this, but it's not being invoked on assembly load.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov - I guess,... based on better [Module initializer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/19/494914.aspx) link provided by Hans Passant module initializer have the same guarantees as static constructors, just runs before. So not running on `Load` makes sense...

Answer (score 3):

A module initializer is the only trouble-maker I can think of.  A simple example of one in C++/CLI:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <msclr\gcroot.h>

using namespace msclr;
using namespace ClassLibrary10;

class Init {
    gcroot<ClassLibrary1::Class1^> managedObject;
public:
    Init() {
        managedObject = gcnew ClassLibrary1::Class1;
    }
} Initializer;
```

The Init() constructor is invoked when the module is loaded through the module initializer, right after it initializes the C runtime.  You are off the hook on this kind of code though in your specific case, Assembly.Load(byte[]) is not capable of loading mixed-mode assemblies.

That is not otherwise a restriction induced by module initializers.  They were added in CLR v2.0 with the specific intention to a similar jobs like this, getting a language runtime to initialize itself before it starts executing any managed code.  The odds that you run into such code should be very, very low.  You'll know it when you see it :)

Comment: If I interpret your statement correctly there is a Santa Claus. so when is there a Santa Claus in .NET? :)

Comment: Sample looks a bit strange to me - indeed creating class *after* load will trigger assembly resolve, but I would not consider creating class to be part of `Load` call. I.e. keeping just `Load` call will not fire resolve at all. Quite possible I completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Hans Obviously, `AssemblyResolve` event can be raised if I _explicitly_ access some code within the loaded assembly (I mentioned that in the question, and your sample also demonstrates that). But in my question I concerned about possible _implicit_ access that can be done by CLR itself while the call to `Assembly.Load(byte[])` has not yet returned.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think you understood the question correctly, your objections make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned -

> In no case I observed the AssemblyResolve event to be raised from
>   inside the Assembly.Load(byte[]) method, it only happened if some code
>   later tried to access types, methods or attributes in the loaded
>   assembly. But I can be missing something here.

The points to note here -

1. While executing code, if a type is referenced in code and the CLR detects that the assembly containing the type is not loaded, then it will load the assembly. *Your observation is correct here.*
2. AssemblyResolve is an event defined in AppDomain type. So this event cannot be raised from inside the Assembly.Load(byte[])

Hence if you have already registered with AssemblyResolve event on the running appdomain and call Assembly.Load(byte[]) it loads the assembly in the current domain.

Now when any type from this loaded assembly is invoked which lets say happens to be calling another type defined in some other assembly, the **AppDomain will call the AssemblyResolve event to try and load that assembly**.

Comment: Can you clarify your point 2. How being defined in different types can prevent an event to being raised?

Comment: Just took your statement strictly when you said "event to be raised from inside the Assembly.Load ...". This statement is not correct as the AssemblyResolve event can be raised only from inside the AppDomain type code (Event can be raised from type that defines it and you subscribe with a event handler to be called when it is raised).

Comment: Thanks. I meant to say "from inside the `Assembly.Load` method or any code it invokes directly or indirectly". There is a private method [`OnAssemblyResolveEvent`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/appdomain.cs#3293) in the `AppDomain` class with a comment "This method is called by the VM". It looks possible that methods from `Assembly` class with native implementation can cause VM to invoke that method.

Comment: The stack trace clearly shows that while `AssemblyResolve` is not called directly from Assembly.Load nor `appDomain.Load` it is present there (with some unmanaged code between load attempt and resolve call).

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527268.aspx) states:

> **How the AssemblyResolve Event Works:**
>
> When you register a handler for the AssemblyResolve event, the handler is invoked whenever the runtime fails to bind to an assembly by name. For example, calling the following methods from user code can cause the AssemblyResolve event to be raised:
>
> 1. An AppDomain.Load method overload or Assembly.Load method overload whose **first argument is a string** that represents the display name of the assembly to load (that is, the string returned by the Assembly.FullName property).
> 2. An AppDomain.Load method overload or Assembly.Load method overload whose first argument is an **AssemblyName object** that identifies the assembly to load.

It doesn't mention the overload receiving a `byte[]`. I looked up in the reference source and it seems that the `Load` which accepts a `string` overload internally calls a method named [`InternalLoad`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/methodimplattribute.cs.html#4159f5c528de6ee8), which before invoking the native `LoadImage` calls [`CreateAssemblyName`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/e6d2ae61ccfdaede.html) and its documentation states:

> Creates AssemblyName. Fills assembly if AssemblyResolve event has been raised.

```
internal static AssemblyName CreateAssemblyName(
           String assemblyString, 
           bool forIntrospection, 
           out RuntimeAssembly   assemblyFromResolveEvent)
{
        if (assemblyString == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("assemblyString");
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        if ((assemblyString.Length == 0) ||
            (assemblyString[0] == '\0'))
            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Format_StringZeroLength"));

        if (forIntrospection)
            AppDomain.CheckReflectionOnlyLoadSupported();

        AssemblyName an = new AssemblyName();

        an.Name = assemblyString;
        an.nInit(out assemblyFromResolveEvent, forIntrospection, true); // This method may internally invoke AssemblyResolve event.
        
        return an;
```

The `byte[]` overload doesn't have this, it simply calls the native `nLoadImage` inside `QCall.dll`. This may explain why `ResolveEvent` isn't invoked.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute following code:

```cs
            var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("some domain");
            var assembly = appDomain.Load(someAssemblyBytes);
```

an `AssemblyResolve` event will be generated. This happens because the assembly is loaded into BOTH domains. First domain is the one you expect it to be - `appDomain` and the assembly resolver for that domain is not called. Second is your current app domain, because you try to access the assembly from it while it's not present there.
Therefore if you execute `appDomain.Load(someAssemblyName);` from domain other than `appDomain` the resolve event will be generated twice, each for each domain.

In such case, if you want to omit the AssemblyResolve attempt (which will fail or will load assembly also into main domain) you have to create proxy class that derives from `MarshalByRefObject` in assembly that will be visible at both domains and use this proxy one to contain proxied class. I.e.:

```cs
    internal class AssemblyVersionProxy : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public Version GetVersion(byte[] assemblyBytes)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes);
            var version = new AssemblyName(assembly.FullName).Version;
            return version;
        }

    }
```

and use it:

```cs
        public Version GetAssemblyVersion(byte[] assemblyBytes)
        {
            var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

            try
            {
                var proxyType = typeof(AssemblyVersionProxy);

                var proxy = (AssemblyVersionProxy)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                    proxyType.Assembly.FullName, proxyType.FullName,
                    false, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null,
                    new object[0], null, new object[0]
                );

                var version = proxy.GetVersion(assemblyBytes);
                return version;
            }
            finally
            {
                AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
            }
        }
```