# c# using Assembly.Load to load multiply assembly from memory

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have 2 assembly should be loaded from memory, I use the following code to implement it but it can't work. Help me, Thank you!

```
        Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("b.dll"));
        var assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("a.dll"));//a.dll referenced b.dll
        var type = assembly.GetTypes().First(p => p.FullName == "Namespace1.Type1");
        type.GetMethod("StaticMethod1", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Invoke(null, new object[] { });//it throw an exception, can't load file or assembly b.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Assembly.Load` to load an assembly from a byte array, loads the assembly but does not register it under its name in the Application Domain. In order to provide your own assembly from a byte array when the runtime is looking to load a specific assembly with a specific name, you implement the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event.

See [this question and the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611154/assemblyresolve-event-fires-when-calling-assembly-loadbyte) for example code.